# How do I create a dates table in Redshift?

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

tl;dr: I want to generate a dates table in Redshift in order to make a report easier to generate.  Preferable without needing large tables already in redshift, needing to upload a csv file.

long version:
I am working on a report where I have to average new items created per day of the week.  The date range could span months or more, so there could be, say, 5 Mondays but only 4 Sundays, which can make the math a little tricky.  Also, I am not guaranteed an instance of a single item per day, especially once a user starts slicing the data.  Which, this is tripping up the BI tool.

The best way to tackle this problem is most likely a dates table.  However, most of the tutorials for dates tables use SQL commands that are not available or not fully supported by Redshift (I'm looking at you, *generate_series*).

**Is there an easy way to generate a dates table in Redshift?**

The code I was attempting to use: (based on this also-not-working recommendation: http://elliot.land/post/building-a-date-dimension-table-in-redshift )

```
CREATE TABLE facts.dates (
  "date_id"              INTEGER                     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

  -- DATE
  "full_date"            DATE                        NOT NULL,

  -- YEAR
  "year_number"          SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "year_week_number"     SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "year_day_number"      SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- QUARTER
  "qtr_number"           SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- MONTH
  "month_number"         SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "month_name"           CHAR(9)                     NOT NULL,
  "month_day_number"     SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- WEEK
  "week_day_number"      SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- DAY
  "day_name"             CHAR(9)                     NOT NULL,
  "day_is_weekday"       SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "day_is_last_of_month" SMALLINT                    NOT NULL
) DISTSTYLE ALL SORTKEY (date_id)
;


INSERT INTO facts.dates
(
   "date_id"
  ,"full_date"
  ,"year_number"
  ,"year_week_number"
  ,"year_day_number"

  -- QUARTER
  ,"qtr_number"

  -- MONTH
  ,"month_number"
  ,"month_name"
  ,"month_day_number"

  -- WEEK
  ,"week_day_number"

  -- DAY
  ,"day_name"
  ,"day_is_weekday"
  ,"day_is_last_of_month"
)
  SELECT
    cast(seq + 1 AS INTEGER)                                      AS date_id,

    -- DATE
    datum                                                         AS full_date,

    -- YEAR
    cast(extract(YEAR FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                    AS year_number,
    cast(extract(WEEK FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                    AS year_week_number,
    cast(extract(DOY FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                     AS year_day_number,

    -- QUARTER
    cast(to_char(datum, 'Q') AS SMALLINT)                         AS qtr_number,

    -- MONTH
    cast(extract(MONTH FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                   AS month_number,
    to_char(datum, 'Month')                                       AS month_name,
    cast(extract(DAY FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                     AS month_day_number,

    -- WEEK
    cast(to_char(datum, 'D') AS SMALLINT)                         AS week_day_number,

    -- DAY
    to_char(datum, 'Day')                                         AS day_name,
    CASE WHEN to_char(datum, 'D') IN ('1', '7')
      THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END                                                    AS day_is_weekday,
    CASE WHEN
      extract(DAY FROM (datum + (1 - extract(DAY FROM datum)) :: INTEGER +
                        INTERVAL '1' MONTH) :: DATE -
                       INTERVAL '1' DAY) = extract(DAY FROM datum)
      THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END                                                    AS day_is_last_of_month
  FROM
    -- Generate days for 81 years starting from 2000.
    (
      SELECT
        '2000-01-01' :: DATE + generate_series AS datum,
        generate_series                        AS seq
      FROM generate_series(0,81 * 365 + 20,1)
    ) DQ
  ORDER BY 1;
```

Which throws this error

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
1 statement failed.
```

... because, I assume, INSERT and *generate_series* are not allowed in the same command in Redshift

Comment: As you've discovered, `generate_series()` cannot be used with actual data because it executes only on the leader node. Your method of generating a numbers table and then joining to it works well. Alternatively, creating a source file in Excel and just importing the results. A dates table like that works very well for reports. Other things you might want to add: public holiday flag, last day of quarter flag, last day of year flag (handy for reports grouped by last date of the period).

Comment: I like those additional columns.  Thanks John!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asking the question, I figured it out.  Oops.

I started with a "facts" schema.

```
CREATE SCHEMA facts;
```

Run the following to start a numbers table:

```
create table facts.numbers
(
  number int PRIMARY KEY
)
;
```

Use this to generate your number list.  I used a million to get started

```
SELECT ',(' || generate_series(0,1000000,1) || ')'
;
```

Then copy-paste the numbers from your results in the query below, after VALUES:

```
INSERT INTO facts.numbers
VALUES
 (0)
,(1)
,(2)
,(3)
,(4)
,(5)
,(6)
,(7)
,(8)
,(9)
-- etc
```

^ Make sure to remove the leading comma from the copy-pasted list of numbers

Once you have a numbers table, then you can generate a dates table (again, stealing code from elliot land http://elliot.land/post/building-a-date-dimension-table-in-redshift ) :

```
CREATE TABLE facts.dates (
  "date_id"              INTEGER                     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

  -- DATE
  "full_date"            DATE                        NOT NULL,

  -- YEAR
  "year_number"          SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "year_week_number"     SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "year_day_number"      SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- QUARTER
  "qtr_number"           SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- MONTH
  "month_number"         SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "month_name"           CHAR(9)                     NOT NULL,
  "month_day_number"     SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- WEEK
  "week_day_number"      SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- DAY
  "day_name"             CHAR(9)                     NOT NULL,
  "day_is_weekday"       SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "day_is_last_of_month" SMALLINT                    NOT NULL
) DISTSTYLE ALL SORTKEY (date_id)
;


INSERT INTO facts.dates
(
   "date_id"
  ,"full_date"
  ,"year_number"
  ,"year_week_number"
  ,"year_day_number"

  -- QUARTER
  ,"qtr_number"

  -- MONTH
  ,"month_number"
  ,"month_name"
  ,"month_day_number"

  -- WEEK
  ,"week_day_number"

  -- DAY
  ,"day_name"
  ,"day_is_weekday"
  ,"day_is_last_of_month"
)
  SELECT
    cast(seq + 1 AS INTEGER)                                      AS date_id,

    -- DATE
    datum                                                         AS full_date,

    -- YEAR
    cast(extract(YEAR FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                    AS year_number,
    cast(extract(WEEK FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                    AS year_week_number,
    cast(extract(DOY FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                     AS year_day_number,

    -- QUARTER
    cast(to_char(datum, 'Q') AS SMALLINT)                         AS qtr_number,

    -- MONTH
    cast(extract(MONTH FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                   AS month_number,
    to_char(datum, 'Month')                                       AS month_name,
    cast(extract(DAY FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                     AS month_day_number,

    -- WEEK
    cast(to_char(datum, 'D') AS SMALLINT)                         AS week_day_number,

    -- DAY
    to_char(datum, 'Day')                                         AS day_name,
    CASE WHEN to_char(datum, 'D') IN ('1', '7')
      THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END                                                    AS day_is_weekday,
    CASE WHEN
      extract(DAY FROM (datum + (1 - extract(DAY FROM datum)) :: INTEGER +
                        INTERVAL '1' MONTH) :: DATE -
                       INTERVAL '1' DAY) = extract(DAY FROM datum)
      THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END                                                    AS day_is_last_of_month
  FROM
    -- Generate days for 81 years starting from 2000.
    (
      SELECT
        '2000-01-01' :: DATE + number AS datum,
        number                        AS seq
      FROM facts.numbers
      WHERE number between 0 and 81 * 365 + 20
    ) DQ
  ORDER BY 1;
```

^ Be sure to set the numbers at the end for the date range you need

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can spin Postgres instance on your local machine, run the code there, export to CSV, then run `CREATE TABLE` portion only in Redshift and load data from CSV. Since this is a one-time operation it's ok to do, this is what I'm actually doing for new Redshift deployments.

Comment: Very good idea, but I figured out a way to do it without uploading a csv.  Does take some copy-paste magic, unfortunately.  I posted my solution below if you have any improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different suggestion for building the `facts.numbers` that does not require manual intervention:

1. Take a system table (guaranteed to exist) of a known or stable size
2. `Cross join` that table to itself enough times to get the desired number of rows
3. Select the `row_number() over (order by 1)` to turn those created records into an ascending set of numbers

Example using the Redshift system table `pg_catalog.pg_operator` (which as of Oct 2020 has 659 records):

```sql
-- Prep, so that you can copy/paste the code sample
create schema if not exists facts;   -- Make sure the schema exists
drop table if exists facts.numbers;  -- Avoid an error if that table already exists;
create table facts.numbers           -- Create the table definition
(
  number int primary key
);

-- The bit you care about
insert into facts.numbers
    select     row_number() over (order by 1) -- return 1..n in place of the original record
    from       pg_catalog.pg_operator a       -- 659 records
    cross join pg_catalog.pg_operator b       -- to get 659^2=434k records 
    cross join pg_catalog.pg_operator c       -- to get 659^3=286M records
    limit      2000000                        -- to limit the result to a reasonable size
;
```

Comment: Great idea, Sam!

Answer (score 1):

Extending great ideas above - small fixes for starting from 2nd day of the year instead of 1st (BI tools should not be happy with this miss) + simplification and fix for flag is_last_day_of_month:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dimensions;   -- Make sure the schema exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dimensions.numbers;  -- Avoid an error if that table already exists;
CREATE TABLE dimensions.numbers           -- Create the table definition
(
  number INT PRIMARY KEY
);
-- Work around for Generate_series() and INSERT INTO by Sam Davey
INSERT INTO dimensions.numbers
    SELECT     row_number() over (order by 1) -- return 1..n in place of the original record
    FROM       pg_catalog.pg_operator a       -- 659 records
    CROSS JOIN pg_catalog.pg_operator b       -- to get 659^2=434k records
    CROSS JOIN pg_catalog.pg_operator c       -- to get 659^3=286M records
    LIMIT      1000000                        -- to limit the result to a reasonable size
; 
-- Elliot solution http://elliot.land/post/building-a-date-dimension-table-in-redshift
CREATE TABLE dimensions.dates (
  "date_id"              INTEGER                     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

  -- DATE
  "full_date"            DATE                        NOT NULL,

  -- YEAR
  "year_number"          SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "year_week_number"     SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "year_day_number"      SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- QUARTER
  "qtr_number"           SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- MONTH
  "month_number"         SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "month_name"           CHAR(9)                     NOT NULL,
  "month_day_number"     SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- WEEK
  "week_day_number"      SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,

  -- DAY
  "day_name"             CHAR(9)                     NOT NULL,
  "day_is_weekday"       SMALLINT                    NOT NULL,
  "day_is_last_of_month" SMALLINT                    NOT NULL
) DISTSTYLE ALL SORTKEY (date_id);

INSERT INTO dimensions.dates
(
   "date_id"
  ,"full_date"
  ,"year_number"
  ,"year_week_number"
  ,"year_day_number"

  -- QUARTER
  ,"qtr_number"

  -- MONTH
  ,"month_number"
  ,"month_name"
  ,"month_day_number"

  -- WEEK
  ,"week_day_number"

  -- DAY
  ,"day_name"
  ,"day_is_weekday"
  ,"day_is_last_of_month"
)
  SELECT
    CAST(seq + 0 AS INTEGER)                                      AS date_id,

    -- DATE
    datum                                                         AS full_date,

    -- YEAR
    CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                    AS year_number,
    CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                    AS year_week_number,
    CAST(EXTRACT(DOY FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                     AS year_day_number,

    -- QUARTER
    CAST(TO_CHAR(datum, 'Q') AS SMALLINT)                         AS qtr_number,

    -- MONTH
    CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                   AS month_number,
    TO_CHAR(datum, 'Month')                                       AS month_name,
    CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM datum) AS SMALLINT)                     AS month_day_number,

    -- WEEK
    CAST(TO_CHAR(datum, 'D') AS SMALLINT)                         AS week_day_number,

    -- DAY
    TO_CHAR(datum, 'Day')                                         AS day_name,
    CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(datum, 'D') IN ('1', '7')
      THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END                                                    AS day_is_weekday,
    CASE WHEN LAST_DAY(datum) = datum THEN 1 ELSE 0 END           AS day_is_last_of_month
  FROM
    -- Generate days for 81 years starting from 2000.
    (
      SELECT
        ('2000-01-01' :: DATE - interval '1 day')::DATE + number AS datum,
        number                        AS seq
      FROM dimensions.numbers
      WHERE number between 0 and  81 * 365 + 20
    ) DQ
  ORDER BY 1;
DROP TABLE dimensions.numbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try this for a cleaner and more efficient approach.

```
create table facts.numbers
(number int PRIMARY KEY);
```

Using recursive function to generate to required amount, took about ~60 sec for 500 million rows. Need to set max_recursion_rows else redshift will stop you from doing too deep of a recursion.

```
SET SESSION max_recursion_rows = 500000000;
SHOW max_recursion_rows;

INSERT INTO facts.numbers
    WITH RECURSIVE number_series (number) AS (
      SELECT 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT number + 1
      FROM number_series
      WHERE number < 500000000 -- Adjust the limit as per your desired number of rows
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM number_series;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).